# Twitter Like URL but with a @'s?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I am making a social networking website, and I can't get this done:
If the url is `http://url.com/@username`, I want it to show the `http://url.com/user?u=username` page, but show `http://url.com/@username` URL.

However, if there is no `@` in the beginning, treat it like a regular URL.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)*$ ./user.php?u=$1
```

The last three lines are what I tried, however that does not work as I wanted it to. I thought it would work because `RewriteRule ^/(\d+)*$` takes any URI after the slash, and rewrites it to `.user.php?u=*`, but that didn't work, so I am looking for some suggestions on what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, this should work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^@(.+?)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

It requires you to have a @ before the username and it passes it as a GET variable (u) However, a person can add other characters which could confuse it as a username.

/@username/muffins

But if you want this, and to have pages per username (ie, /@username/info, /@username/about, etc) you can just use the [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() function in PHP.

If you just want it to get the username and nothing else, you can try

```
RewriteRule ^@([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: What about say `/@username?about`?

Comment: You can use PHP's explode function. Count to see if there are more than 1 parts (part 1 = username, 2 = page, etc) Then take the 2nd part and use it as the page, if it doesnt then display the main page.

Comment: Alright, and one last thing, if I URL is `http://localhost/@`, it gives me a 404 warning, is it possible to make it so if there is nothing after the **@**, it will redirect it back to index?

Comment: Fairly simple, add this to the end of the rewrite url
RewriteRule ^@$ /index.php [r=301,nc]